# Pass environment variable to PyTest based on Github commit message

Tags: python, yaml, pytest, github-actions, travis-ci

In `.yml` we can do

```yaml
jobs:
    build-conda:
        if: "! contains(toJSON(github.event.commits.*.message), '[skip ci]')"
```

to skip a build if commit message  contains `[skip ci]`. Likewise, I'd like to pass an environment variable to the Python test scripts, like so (pseudocode):

```py
if "[my msg]" in github_commit_message:
    os.environ["MY_VAR"] = "1"
else:
    os.environ["MY_VAR"] = "0"
```

or just pass the whole `github_commit_message` to the env var. I'm using Github actions, but Travis is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a workflow environment variable based on whether the commit message contains a certain substring.

For the example below, the variable `CONTAINS_PYTHON` is set to `'true'` if the commit message contains the string `[python]`.

In the run step, the value is printed using python. Note that this assumes it is run on a runner that has python installed and on the PATH. This is the case for `ubuntu-latest`, but possibly not for self-hosted runners. Therefore, if you get a message like "python not found", make sure to also include the [setup-python](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) action.

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CONTAINS_PYTHON: ${{ contains(toJSON(github.event.commits.*.message), '[python]') }}
    steps:
      - run: python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("CONTAINS_PYTHON"))'
```

Comment: No longer needed but I'll trust it works, thanks